# Getting output 4 instead of 1

Tags: python

Write a Python code to take one integer as input and store it in a variable
namely, myNum. The output is a summation of digits in the tens and the
hundreds places. Assume that you will never enter 1-digit or 2-digit integer
as an input. (Hint, you have to use modulo and floor division operators,
and few variables.)

Sample 1

Enter a number: 103
The result is 1

`

```
def getSum(n):
    
    sum = 0
    while (n != 0):
       
        sum = sum + (n % 10)
        n = n//10
       
    return sum
   
n = 103
print(getSum(n))
```

`

Comment: because the question only asks for the sum of the hundreds and tens, where as you're adding the digit too

Comment: can u please fix my code?

Comment: find a way to replace the final digit to 0 then run your code, or maybe put another n = n//10 before the while loop

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option if you only want to handle hundreds + tens:

```
def getSum(n):
    n = n//10                # first get rid of units
    n, total = divmod(n, 10) # get tens
    total += n%10            # get hundreds
    return total

getSum(1234)
# 5

getSum(234)
# 5
```

Comment: question asks for sum of hundreds and tens, not sure how it wants thousands and above handled

Comment: @EmiOB I was sure it was hundreds and thousands, my bad, it's an identical logic however (see update)